# sending data from one node js to another and displaying the sent data on the other node js

Tags: node.js, http, ejs

i am trying to send data from one node js server to another and display the information sent. Example server A and server B. Server A sent data to server B and server B will display the information sent by server A and response with a answer back to server A. Basically my program is like a payment page and a bank-server page. Sending payment details to the bank-server and if the bank-server clicked accept, it will send back to the payment page and continue the transaction.

This is my code for the payment page:

```
var postData = JSON.stringify({ user: cardDetails });

    const options = {
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: 3001,
        path: '/bank',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'accept': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const httpreq = http.request(options, (res) => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chuck) => {
            console.log(`BODY: ${chuck}`);
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
    });

    httpreq.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    })

    //write data to request body
    httpreq.write(postData);
    httpreq.end();
```

This is my code for the bank-server side:
App.js

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serverPort = 3000;
var httpServer = require('http').Server(app);

// ejs template path
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "server/views/pages"));
// view engine setup
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//import order tracking
var bank = require('./server/controllers/bank');

app.get("/bank-server", bank.bankSystem);
app.post("/bank", bank.add);

console.log("Connected!")
app.listen(3001);
```

This is my bank.js code:

```
exports.add = function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body.user.cardName);
    res.sendStatus(200);

};

exports.bankSystem = function (req, res){
    console.log("Bank Page Working!")
        res.render('bankServer', {
            name: "empty"
        })
    }
```

Lastly my bankServer.ejs code:

```
<h1>Connection Worked!</h1>
<p>Card Name is <%= name %></p>
```

[This is the output from payment node js. CardName entered = raysonkira1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZIrz.png)
[This is the output from bankserver node js. received cardName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoKQc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Bank.js, you are just sending the status and not response.

```
exports.add = function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body.user.cardName);
    res.sendStatus(200);
    // send the response data here, for example
    res.send("Hello from the bank!");
};
```

[reference](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

Comment: but how do i make the sent details appear in my ejs file?

Comment: `console.log(BODY: ${chuck});` is doing this right?

Comment: Yup! It shows OK. Meaning the server responded using the res.sendstatus

Comment: `res.on(` **`'data'`** `, (chuck) => {console.log(BODY: ${chuck});});`  will show response _data_ , status code is retrived via `res.statusCode` See first example in the http [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

Comment: Ah yea ik about that. But what can i do to make the details appear on my bankserver.ejs. since i got the info req.body.user in bank node js side.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the rabitmq for data transfer or sencond solution is both side initialize the API your side you can post the data and bank side Get the data